# Nested class decorators which are also descriptor classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-descriptors

I have a situation where I need to use nested decorators like below,

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,v):
        print("A.init")
    @deco1
    @deco2
    def m(self, a):
        print("A.m")
```

Decorators are implemented like below,

```
class deco1(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print("deco1.init")
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("deco1.call.before")
        r = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("deco1.call.after")
        return r
    def __get__(self, o, c):
        print("deco1.get")
        return MethodType(self, o)

class deco2(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print("deco2.init")
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("deco2.call.before")
        r = self.f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("deco2.call.after")
        return r
    def __get__(self, o, c):
        print("deco2.get")
        return MethodType(self, o)
```

Problem is descriptor method on deco2 class isn't being called and I require that to be called.
When I do something like below,

```
aa = A(100)
aa.m(10)
```

**Actual**,

```
deco1.get
deco1.call.before
deco2.call.before
A.m
deco2.call.after
deco1.call.after
```

**Expected**

```
deco1.get
deco1.call.before
deco2.get   #deco2.__get__ to be called
deco2.call.before
A.m
deco2.call.after
deco1.call.after
```

I need to have separate decorators for a reason. With that in mind, how could I make this work ? Also, if someone can explain why deco2.**get** isn't called, that would be great ! Thanks.

Using Python 3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

deco2.get was called [once] when the decorated `m` was created.

The decoration

```
@deco1
@deco2
def m
```

can be rewritten as

```
m = deco1(deco2(m))
```

so when deco1 argument was calculated deco2.get was called.

Comment: In my example deco2.get was never called. Also,  decorator methods (get etc) are called when the object is referenced. i.e. when I did aa.m (m is instance of deco1). Regardless still doesn't answer my question as to why deco2.get wasn't called (deco2 instance is referenced within deco1)